# How to handle blocked user verification email?

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

Some of the user verification emails are being blocked by some smtp servers(I use sendgrid to send emails). When email is recieved by the user everything works fine but how should I be handling user verification in case user doesnt recieve my emails?

```
 const msg = {
     to: user.email,
    from: {
    email: 'test@ishakertem.com.au',
    name: 'Ishak Ertem'
    },
  templateId: 'd-1d9532c9769c44d3825256edc1061bb5',
  dynamic_template_data: {
   name: user.firstName,
    verifyLink: link
     }
}
             
 sgMail.send(msg).then(()=>{
   console.log('Message sent')

})
```

Domain and link branding are verified via sendgrid.